# SQL Query error message showing 'id not found' in Spring Boot

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I don't know what may be causing this error.
I need to sum all the values of column totalareceber from tb_oscolab in a way that each line contains a colaborador_id and its total value. The period must be within the dates from another table named tb_os as data_inicio.
This is my query in Spring boot and it seems to be correct:

```
public interface OSColabRepository extends JpaRepository<OSColab, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT colaborador_id, SUM(totalareceber) FROM tb_oscolab INNER JOIN tb_os ON tb_oscolab.os_id = tb_os.id WHERE tb_os.data_inicio BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY colaborador_id", nativeQuery = true) 
    List<OSColab> getOSColabSumBetweenDates(@Param("startDate") Date startDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate);

}
```

But it is returning:
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.

But there is a column id in both tb_os and tb_oscolab

OS

```
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

OSCOLAB

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I found these articles, but I could not understand the solution very well as I'm a starter:
[SQL Query returning column 'id' not found in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913095/sql-query-returning-column-id-not-found-in-spring-boot)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/473427/java-sql-sqlexception-column-id-not-found

Could someone please help me to identify the problem here?

Comment: You only select some columns, not the complete object of type `OSColab` which you exect as the result. Try changing `List<OSColab> getOSColabSumBetweenDates`to `List<Object[]> getOSColabSumBetweenDates`

Comment: @Jens That's it! That is exactly what I needed to do. Now I see what was wrong with my code. If you write it as a reply I'll flag it as the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only select some columns, not the complete object of type `OSColab` which you exect as the result. Changing `List<OSColab> getOSColabSumBetweenDates` to `List<Object[]> getOSColabSumBetweenDates`

Answer (score -1):

try doing this

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT colaborador_id, SUM(totalareceber) FROM tb_oscolab INNER JOIN tb_os ON tb_oscolab.id = tb_os.id WHERE tb_os.data_inicio BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY colaborador_id", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: But tb_oscolab.id will never be equals to tb_os.id
The reference to tb_os in tb_oscolab is os_id, not tb_oscolab.id

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).